# 6502 interrupts when RDY is low

Tags: 6502, interrupt

If the NMI line goes from high to low when the RDY is low, is the NMI  detected, so that when RDY goes high, NMI is performed ?

Or is the NMI discarded when it occurs when RDY is low ?

(In case of NMI line goes high again before RDY become high)

Comment: NMI is supposed to be edge triggered, so it should happen even RDY goes inactive, but hopefully somebody can answer with empirical evidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Yes, it will be detected and performed.

---

Lets look at the signals:

NMI

- is edge triggered. As soon as a high/low edge comes, the NMI-FF will be set
- Retriggering requires NMI being high again before and during the rising edge of PHI2.
- NMI will not be triggered again unless a new edge comes along *after* vector pull
- NMI reaction may be delayed up to two cycles
- In any case the actual instruction will always be finished first
- NMI during IRQ handling (before first instruction of IRQ routine) will interrupt after the first instructon is finished.
- Interrupts are always delayed by one instruction when issued during the last cycle of a branch taken within the same page.
- NMI is not delayed during a CLI/SEI/PLP (like INT is)
- NMI (or INT) during a BRK will skip execution of the BRK handling

RDY

- RDY will only be (secure) detected safe when pulled during pase 1
- RDY will not take effect during a write cycle (NMOS only)
- RDY does not affect any other operation beside repeating the actual (memory) cycle

In combination this means:

- NMI detection will happen during RDY
- NMI will start as usual after the actual instruction is finished
- Having RDY applied for one or more times during the actual instruction will not change NMI operation
- Any length of RDY application will not change NMI operation.

Bottom Line: **It will work as expected - but there are still many issues to screw up NMI timing**.

Comment: So if I understand well, NMI high -> low edge is detected independently of the clock (no matter phi1 or phi2) but the reset of the NMI edge flip-flop is performed on the phi2 ?

Comment: @Johnmph Exactly.

Comment: If a program performs D0 FE (BNE to self) at a page offset less than $FE, could that block interrupts forever?  Or would an interrupt which becomes pending just before the first execution of that instruction fire after the second?

Comment: @supercat No, AFAIK. When hitting during the last cycle of a branch it will be delayed by one instruction. In this case it will be executed after the next branch.

Comment: @Raffzahn: Would another way of saying that be to say that the decision of whether or not an interrupt should occur on the instruction following a non-page-crossing branch is made a cycle *sooner* than normal?

Answer (score 1):

In old 6502 block diagrams, the three hardware interrupts `/RST /IRQ /NMI` go into an "interrupt logic" block which feeds directly into the instruction decoder, and are not directly influenced by `RDY` or even `Phi2`.  This tells me that even on original hardware, the edge-trigger circuit for `/NMI` is asynchronous and that an edge will be detected at any time.  This is what you'd expect of an interrupt signal.

On the current-production WDC W65C02S, you can make a stronger assertion, because `RDY` is physically pulled low by the CPU when a `WAI` instruction is executed, and is only allowed to go high again when an interrupt is received (any of the three).  Thus `/NMI` must be detected even when `RDY` is low.

Comment: This is what I expected too but in the following link, it's says that edge is detected during phi2 (Detailed Interrupt Behaviour section) : https://wiki.nesdev.com/w/index.php/CPU_interrupts

Comment: Since RDY is sometimes described (including by WDC) as holding the internal state of the CPU in the Phi2 phase, that doesn't preclude very much.